# Big O and Little o

Tags: big-o

If algorithm A has complexity O(n) and algorithm B has complexity o(n^2), what, if anything, can we say about the relationship between A and B? Note: the complexity of A is expressed using big-Oh, and the complexity of B is expressed using little-Oh.

Comment: That B was invented before A? :)

Comment: hOmewOrk perhaps?

Comment: @ssg - or the new developer guy made B as an "improvement" to A, because he used certain techniques he read about in an overhyped blog...

Comment: @hyperdude: it's fine to ask homework questions on SO, but they should be marked as such. Also, show that you've at least tried to solve the problem and ask about the specific part that's causing you difficulties. Read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: <old-man-voice> back in my day, we did not have stack overflow to answer by CS homework </old-man-voice>

Comment: Anytime someone uses the words "what, if anything, can we say," you can be 99% assured it's homework.  No real human being talks like that. ;)

Answer (score 4):

As [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation) expressively puts it,

> "f(x) is little-o of g(x)" ... means
>   that g(x) grows *much* faster than
>   f(x)

(my ellipsis and emphasis) -- putting it in the somber way that "mathematician wannabes" seem to require, the limit of `f(x)/g(x)` tends to 0 at the limit when x tends to infinity.

So, there's not all that much we can say: `A` grows no faster than `n`, `B` grows *much* slower than `n` squared, it might even be the *same* algorithm you're talking about;-) -- just as if you were expressing the same constraints verbally ("A is no worse than linear, B is better than quadratic").

Indeed, anything `O(n)` *will* be `o(n squared)`, though not vice versa; for example, `x` to the power of `K` for some constant `K` is going to be `O(n)` for any `K <= 1`, but it will be `o(n squared)` for any `K < 2`.  Other functions that are `o(n squared)` but not `O(N)` include the commonly-encountered `n log n`.

Comment: if "g(x) grows much faster than f(x)" is to be taken literally, then it's logically impossible that f and g are the same... ;)

Comment: That is a sloppy summary from wikipedia on mathematically precise terms.

Comment: @Frantic, anybody's of course welcome to click through and read the whole wikipedia entry -- I chose to quote the short, expressive summary because I find it intuitively useful.  I don't find your short, pointers-free answer to be **any** use at all, and obviously given my downvote you must think similarly of mine, but surely the fact that at least I *do* point to something objectively useful must give mine the objective edge;-).

Comment: @FranticPedantic - Feel free to correct the wikipedia article if you know it's wrong. It's helpful that someone who knows it actually writes about it. :)